# Speed up my data reading in python?

Tags: python, pandas

My current code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def data_reader(filename, rowname):
    with open(filename, newline='') as fp:
        yield from (row[1:] for row in csv.reader(fp, skipinitialspace=True)
            if row[0] == rowname)
File = 'data.csv'
ASA = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_reader(File, 'ASA'))
GDS = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_reader(File, 'GDS'))
SCD = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_reader(File, 'SCD'))
ASF = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_reader(File, 'ASF'))
ADC = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_reader(File, 'ADC'))
DFS = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_reader(File, 'DFS'))
DCS = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_reader(File, 'DCS'))
DFDS = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_reader(File, 'DFDS'))
```

It is reading data that looks like this:

```
legend, useless data, useless data, DCS, useless data, sped, air, xds, sas, dac
legend, useless data, useless data, GDS, useless data, sped, air
Legend, useless data, useless data, ASA, useless data, sped, air, gnd 
ASA, 231, 123, 12
GDS, 12, 1
DCS, 13, 12, 123, 12, 4
ASA, 123, 132, 12
and so on for couple of millions....
```

I am trying to write an IF statement that looks something like this:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_reader(
    if rowname = 'ASA'
        ASA.append(row)
    elif rowname = 'GDS'
        GDS.append(row)
```

and so on. Would this be faster? currently it is taking about 1 minute to run my code and plot one graph. I am sure it will be much longer when I have about 10-15 plots to do. I have tried different methods of writing the if/elseif statement but I am not having any luck doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from disk is the bottleneck here, so we should try to avoid reading the file more than once. If you have enough memory to parse the entire CSV into a dict of lists, then you could use

```
import csv
import collections
import pandas as pd

def data_reader(filename):
    dfs = collections.defaultdict(list)
    columns = dict()
    with open(filename, newline='') as fp:
        for row in csv.reader(fp, skipinitialspace=True):
            key = row[0].upper()
            if key == 'LEGEND':
                name = row[3]
                columns[name] = row
            else:
                dfs[key].append(row[1:])

    for key in dfs:
        num_cols = max(len(row) for row in dfs[key])
        dfs[key] = pd.DataFrame(dfs[key], columns=columns[key][-num_cols:])
    return dfs

filename = 'data.csv'
dfs = data_reader(filename)

for key in dfs:
    print(dfs[key])
```

---

The loop

```
for row in csv.reader(fp, skipinitialspace=True):
    key = row[0].upper()
    ...
    dfs[key].append(row[1:])
```

loads the CSV into a dict, `dfs`. The dict keys are strings like `'ASA'`,
`'GDS'` and `'DCS'`. The dict values are lists of lists.

The other loop

```
for key in dfs:
    ...
    dfs[key] = pd.DataFrame(dfs[key], columns=columns[key][:-num_cols:])
```

converts the lists of lists to DataFrames.

---

The `if-statement`:

```
if key == 'LEGEND':
    name = row[3]
    columns[name] = row
else:
    dfs[key].append(row[1:])
```

records the row in the `columns` dict if the row begins with `LEGEND` (with or without capitalization), or otherwise records the row in the `dfs` dict.

Later in the `for-loop`:

```
for key in dfs:
    num_cols = max(len(row) for row in dfs[key])
    dfs[key] = pd.DataFrame(dfs[key], columns=columns[key][-num_cols:])
```

The `key`s are strings such as `'ASA'`.  For each key, the number of columns is
obtained by finding the maximum length of the rows in `dfs[key]`.

`columns[key]` returns the corresponding legend row for `key`.
`columns[key][-num_cols:]` returns the last `num_cols` values from that row.

---

The result returned by `data_reader` is a dict of DataFrames:

```
In [211]: dfs['ASA']
Out[211]: 
  sped  air gnd 
0  231  123   12
1  123  132   12

In [212]: dfs['GDS']
Out[212]: 
  sped air
0   12   1

In [213]: dfs['DCS']
Out[213]: 
  sped air  xds sas dac
0   13  12  123  12   4
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very detailed answer. I will look closer at it and see if I can figure it out it all.

Comment: I am struggling a little trying to implement this. The reason being is that I forgot to mention that there is a bit of useless data between the legend and the key it self. I have edit the original question to reflect it.

Comment: In the rows that begin with `legend` do you know in what column the `DCS`, `GDS`, `ASA` values appear? For example, are they always in the fourth column?

Comment: Yes, they are always on the 4th column.

Comment: I also edited my data just to test out the code. However, I got this error: AssertionError: 18 columns passed, passed data had 19 columns on his line dfs[key] = pd.DataFrame(dfs[key], columns=columns[key])

Comment: I've modified the code to show how you could extract the column names despite the "useless data". It relies on the `key`s always being in the 4th column, and the column names always appearing at the end of the legend lines.

Comment: Awesome that worked! wow I learned so much from this one. This is something I have not done before. I usually manually extract information. One question though. Where would I need to go to learn how to manipulate this? Would keeping it in dict easier or convert it to panda list be better for me? I am going to do a lot of data manipulation on each row and a lot of plotting and I am good with list, but never used dict before and I am trying to find documents on it to go through it but not having any luck.

Comment: Start by reading the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). It is a good place to [learn about dicts](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). The [official Pandas tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html) is the right place to start learning Pandas. Pandas builds on top of NumPy so to really understand Pandas it is useful to also [know NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html).

Comment: Ploughing through these tutorials will take some time. If you want to build a strong foundation in Python programming, there is no substitute for reading/practicing these tutorials thoroughly. But if you just want to solve your current programming problem, skip around through the tutorials and try learning just the parts you need. Try to write code to solve your problem. If you run into trouble, post your code and ask a question on Stackoverflow. Good luck!

Comment: Knowing which data structure to use (dict vs DataFrame for instance) intimately depends on exactly what you are trying to calculate. If you post a question showing the calculation using basic Python loops, lists and/or dicts, and ask if there is a better way using Pandas you may get some helpful responses.

Comment: Hi again. I have been banging my head against the wall for this problem for the past week and I can't figure it out. I came across a data that I believe in the key it says it has 3 columns but in the data itself it only has 2 columns. So I am getting this error when I run it: "AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns" The error is on the line dfs[key] = pd.DataFrame(dfs[key], columns=columns[key][-num_cols:]). Is this the correct thinking? then should I just say ignore it or is there a better way to approach this. By the way thanks a lot for you help I really appreciate it.

Comment: Also is it possible to know which line in the data file itself that it has the issue with? I looked at the traceback and it doesn't say anything about which line in my data file.

Comment: That AssertionError could happen if two rows of the CSV have different lengths for the same `key`. I've modified the code (to use `num_cols = max(len(row) for row in dfs[key])`) so that `num_cols` equals the *maximum* length of all the rows in `dfs[key]`. I should have used that from the beginning. Now, if a row is shorter than expected, the missing values will be filled with `None` or `NaN` (depending on the dtype of the column).

Comment: Man you are a legend. I finally saw it last night that one of the rows was actually longer than what the length was. Thank you again that fixed it.

Comment: So this skips any row that has more than the Max number of rows in the Legend correct?

Comment: Actually, no rows are skipped. The DataFrame gets as many columns as is required
to display the *longest* data row. The column names are found from the
corresponding legend line. As long as the legend line contains at least as many
field names, you will be fine -- at least there will be no Exception. If the
longest data row has more items than the corresponding legend line, an
AssertionError will be raised.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
ASA = df.ix[df[0] == "ASA"]
# etc ...
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, how would that work? how does it know to look for which row for ASA?

Comment: i made a mistake, see my edit,  for how you index by the first column containing a certain value

Comment: I got the error of: CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 10 fields in line 3, saw 18. I believe because my data has different row numbers.

Comment: Also, how does this make it faster? aren't I reading the dataframe every time I look for ASA or GDS?

Comment: you can do `pd.read_csv('data.csv', names = range(18)` if you know that the maximum number of columns is 18. It should fast to do the subsetting because the dataframe will be in memory rather than having to read from disk each time.

Comment: Ah that worked, little extra NAN data that I have but not an issue. I do have a question though. How would I copy data after the ASA only? because right now it is copying the ASA column and when I am trying to convert it to float using ASA = ASA.astype(float) I get a could not convert string to str because ASA is in the dataframe.

Comment: you can select a range of columns numerically using `iloc` and the `:` syntax, the command for "all columns starting at column 1" would be `ASA.iloc[:, 1:]`

Comment: I see. One last question. Could you elaborate exactly what is going on in the df.ix[df[0] part. I went through the data sheet for the past couple of hours trying to understand it but having hard time figuring it out. Thanks!

Comment: take a look at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html `df[0]` refers to the first column of your dataframe (which contains your labels)